# StreamReader C# error: process cannot access the file because it is being used

Tags: c#, streamreader

so im having this issue when trying to read a file.

I am getting the filenames from a directory and then looping through them to insert them into a db. but i keep getting an error. file cannot be accessed when i try Streamread the file.

Here is all my code and this is the only code that actually works with this directory at all so no other processes could lock this file.

i keep getting the error at this line "using (var reader = new StreamReader(localPath))" saying this "The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process"

```
public async Task<ResponseBase> GetCsvAsync()
    {
        var response = new ResponseBase();
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"~/App_Data/IosStats/ToProcess"));//Assuming Test is your Folder
            //FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.csv"); //Getting Text files
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Getting Text files
            var filenames = new List<string>();
            foreach (var file in Files)
            {
                filenames.Add(file.Name);
            }

            foreach (var filename in filenames)
            {
                var localPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"~/App_Data/IosStats/ToProcess/{filename}");
                localPath = localPath ?? Path.GetFileName(filename);
                var outputFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(localPath);

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(localPath))
                //using (var reader = new StreamReader($"{d}/{file.Name}"))
                {
                    var counter = 0;
                    var columnName = "";
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        counter = counter + 1;
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        var values = line.Split(',');
                        var currentRow = new AppDownload();
                        var currentAppHistory = DbContext.AppDownloads.Where(x => x.Platform == AppPlatform.IOS).ToList();
                        if (counter == 5)
                        {
                            columnName = values[1];
                        }

                        if (counter <= 4 & columnName != "")
                        {
                            var csvDate = Convert.ToDateTime(values[0]);
                            var isAlreadyLogged = currentAppHistory.Where(x => x.CsvDate == csvDate).ToList();
                            var currentReplacementRow = new AppDownload();
                            if (isAlreadyLogged.Count == 0)
                            {
                                currentRow.CsvDate = Convert.ToDateTime(values[0]);
                                currentRow.PackageName = "Dialdirect Insurance";
                                currentRow.Platform = AppPlatform.IOS;
                                currentRow.InsertedTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
                                switch (columnName)
                                {
                                    case "Active Devices":
                                        currentRow.ActiveDeviceInstalls = Convert.ToInt16(values[1]);
                                        break;

                                    case "Installations":
                                        currentRow.DailyDeviceInstalls = Convert.ToInt16(values[1]);
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        columnName = "";
                                        break;
                                }

                                DbContext.AppDownloads.Add(currentRow);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                currentReplacementRow = isAlreadyLogged.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CsvDate == csvDate);
                                switch (columnName)
                                {
                                    case "Active Devices":
                                        currentReplacementRow.ActiveDeviceInstalls = Convert.ToInt16(values[1]);
                                        break;

                                    case "Installations":
                                        currentReplacementRow.DailyDeviceInstalls = Convert.ToInt16(values[1]);
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        columnName = "";
                                        break;
                                }

                                DbContext.AppDownloads.Add(currentReplacementRow);
                            }
                            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                            var sourceFile = localPath;
                            var destinationFile = HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"~/App_Data/IosStats/Processed/{filename}");
                            System.IO.File.Move(localPath, destinationFile);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            response.Success = true;
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToExceptionless().Submit();
            response.Success = false;
            return response;
            throw;
        }

    }
```

I am pulling my hair out because it does not want to read the file. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe if you refactor that code, the issue would arise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing the `outputFile` stream, nor do you seem to be using it at all.

Another issue further down is this line:

```
System.IO.File.Move(localPath, destinationFile);
```

You are moving the file while holding it open by the `StreamReader`.

Comment: Where would i close the output file stream. the error occurs when trying to read the file into the streamreader

Comment: Yes since `var outputFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(localPath);` is locking it.

Comment: @AndreaVisnenzaAndy You are opening it for writing **before** opening it for reading, hence it's blocked.

Comment: Also, you copy the filenames to a list just to reconstruct their paths which you already have ... ?

Comment: @Fildor i was trying to see if the getdirectory was blocking it. Thanks alot for the answers. i just removed the 
                var outputFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(localPath); because i do not need to write to file. just read ffrom it. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

If even after fixing the issue raised by @Magnus, check the directory permissions, whether you have write access to it. If you do have, then check whether there are any group policies enforced thru anti-virus software. If there are no specific policies related to editing that file in that folder, check whether there are any restrictions on file types. Hope this fixes your issues.